# IOS campaigns from Dynamic Links are not seen in BigQuery

Tags: flutter, google-bigquery, firebase-dynamic-links

The problem is that we see very little amount referrer campaigns from the iOS in BigQuery. The expected number should be x100 times more. And Android campaign numbers are correct.

We are using `flutter v1.1.1+64` and the `firebase_dynamic_links v0.2.0+3` flutter library for tracking.

Dynamic Links have App Store campaign configured (`pt`, `ct` and `mt` parameters) and we can see these campaigns in the iTunes Connect.

In BigQuery I'm looking at the `traffic_source.*` columns and also at `firebase_campaign` events.

- Where the problem can be?
- How do IOS Dynamic Links work under the hood?
- Are there any ways of debugging on which step the problem is?

Comment: Do you have any solution for this. On my side, I only can see firebase_campaign event just for Android, but not for iOS devices :S